# BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource

Tags: spring, hibernate

Im using hibernate 3.2.7 and spring 3.2.8. The error is ***

> **": Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of
>   init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   ServletContext resource [/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml] cannot be
>   resolved to URL because it does not exist".

---

I try to put hibernate.cfg.xml in src, in webinf and classpath: , but it still dont find it.This is my error stack trace:

```
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext
> resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method
> failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> ServletContext resource [/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml] cannot be
> resolved to URL because it does not exist     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1512)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>   at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:610)
>   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
>   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:602)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:521)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:462)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>   at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5210)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:670)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1839)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource
> [/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it
> does not exist    at
> org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getURL(ServletContextResource.java:154)
>   at
> org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBe
```

My spring-servlet is:

> 

```
<bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix">
    <value>/</value>
  </property>
  <property name="suffix">
    <value>.xhtml</value>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
    p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
    <value>resources/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.SetBigStringTryClob">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">0</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">0</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

    <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

>

Comment: Try and use `classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml` instead of `resources/hibernate.cfg.xml` Seems like the url `resources/hibernate.cfg.xml` doesn't exist which is correct. When using maven style, you don't need the `resources` reference. This is assuming your maven file structure is `src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `configLocation` of `LocalSessionFactoryBean` is of type `Resource` and you can specify the type of resource with a prefix, for example:

```
classpath:resources/hibernate.cfg.xml
```

By default, in ServletContext, if you dont specify the prefix, the resource use the class `ServletContextResource`. From Spring Documentation:

> 5.3.4 ServletContextResource
>
> This is a Resource implementation for ServletContext resources, interpreting relative paths within the relevant web application's root directory.
>
> This always supports stream access and URL access, but only allows java.io.File access when the web application archive is expanded and the resource is physically on the filesystem. Whether or not it's expanded and on the filesystem like this, or accessed directly from the JAR or somewhere else like a DB (it's conceivable) is actually dependent on the Servlet container.

Then, you need put the prefix or put the resource in the root of the application.

You can see all abaout resources in [Resources](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html) from spring documentation.